# Close browser after several test classes

Tags: java, selenium

I work on an automated testing framework and I need to close the browser after passing tests on several test classes.

The package structure of the project is similar to this:

- PackageA

  - SomeTestClass1
  - SomeTestClass2
  - ...
- PackageB

  - SomeOtherTestClass1
  - SomeOtherTestClass2
  - ...

Note: There can be multiple levels of packages inside one another.

If I use @AfterClass or @AfterAll JUnit annotations I have to close the browser at the 'end' of each test class.
My framework requires launching the browser (as a static variable) and closing it only one time to speed up execution and avoid losing time for every browser launch and login, as I currently have a big number of tests that need to be run each night.

Is there any possiblity I could achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

In **JUnit 4**, you could use the concept of [Rule](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Rule.html) in conjunction with extending [TestWatcher](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) abstract class (`org.junit.rules.TestWatcher`). 
Hence you won't have to close the browser in a method annotated with *@AfterClass*.

e.g.

```
public class StartFinishTestWatcher extends TestWatcher {
    @Override
    protected void starting(Description description) {
        System.out.println("Starting test: " + description.getDisplayName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void finished(Description description) {
        System.out.println("Finishing test: " + description.getDisplayName());
        // close the browser here
    }
}
```

Then you would use this class in a [RuleChain](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/RuleChain.html), in the test class(es) where you want to close the browser.

```
public class MyTestInWhichIWantBrowserToClose {

    @Rule
    public RuleChain ruleChain = buildTestRuleChain();

    private RuleChain buildTestRuleChain() { // could be made protected and put in a superclass

        return RuleChain.outerRule(new StartFinishTestWatcher());
    }
}
```

---

In **JUnit 5** you could create custom [Test Suites](https://howtodoinjava.com/junit5/junit5-test-suites-examples/) and implement [BeforeTestExecutionCallback](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/BeforeTestExecutionCallback.html) and (in your case) [AfterTestExecutionCallback](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/AfterTestExecutionCallback.html) interfaces in one of your base class.

You would then implement the custom logic which decides to close the browser in method `public void afterTestExecution(ExtensionContext context)`.